# Change ViewController if no internet

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, viewcontroller

I want to know if there is a method that goes to another `viewcontroller` if there is no internet. Please help

Cheers,

Palash

Comment: My app requires internet and if internet is not available it will not work so I want it to redirect to a view controller or xib

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reachability class for this purpose
https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

Usage:

```
    let reachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()

reachability.whenReachable = { reachability in
    if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi() {
        println("Reachable via WiFi")
    } else {
        println("Reachable via Cellular")
    }
     //Load your viewController
}
reachability.whenUnreachable = { reachability in
    println("Not reachable")
   //Load your viewController
}

reachability.startNotifier()
```

Comment: Could you translate this to swift